# Can't login to another account in xcode (This device is already associated with other accounts in the apple developer program)

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

Trying to figure out with the issue, when logging the another apple account in xcode. After receiving an sms from the phone and entered the code, I've got this error message: "This device is already associated with other accounts in the apple developer program. please use a different device"[hot it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPIx3.png)

I've tried to remove previous certificates, another accounts which was added to the xcode, moving xcode to defaults settings. But nothing of this didn't help.